# Value of protocol type '*' cannot conform to '*'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-protocols

I am facing the above error while trying this:

```
    protocol Style {}
    
    struct StyleA: Style {}
    struct StyleA: Style {}
    struct StyleA: Style {}

    struct Preset: Identifiable {
        let id: UUID = UUID()
        let title: String
        let style: Style
    }

    extension View {
        public func applyStyle<S>(_ style: S) where S : Style {
            // USe the style here
        }
    }
    

    // Initializg the data
    static let mockedData: [Preset] = [
        .init(title: "Title A", style: StyleA()),
        .init(title: "Title A", style: StyleB()),
        .init(title: "Title A", style: StyleC()),
    ]
    
// This line gives the error
    myView.applyStyle(mockedData.first!.style)
```

How can I fix it? Shouldn't it resolve the concrete type?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thats because in swift protocol does not confirm to itself. read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself

Comment: one issue is that u have to make "protocol Style"  public( since ur function is public

Comment: I guess , If u use applyStyle inside a body of a view ...then this function doesnt return a view , so that is also a function ...please add reproducable code .

Answer (score 1):

You're running into the problem of [protocols not conforming to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself). Your problem can be easily solved by making `applyStyle` non-generic, since `Style` can be used as a concrete type.

```
extension View {
    public func applyStyle(_ style: Style) {
        // USe the style here
    }
}
```

Comment: I would just remove `Style` from the method name `func apply(_ style: Style)`

Comment: @LeoDabus in that case, I think `func apply(style: Style)` would read more naturally, but this isn't really related to OP's question.

Comment: Sure not related to the question. Anyway I think that when there is a single parameter `style` is not needed and generally not used

Answer (score 0):

Since the Preset member style is Style, not any concrete type, you don't need the applyStyle to be generic, you can simply say:

```
  public func applyStyle(_ style: Style)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public protocol Style {}

struct StyleA: Style {}
struct StyleB: Style {}
struct StyleC: Style {}

struct Preset: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let title: String
    let style: Style
}

extension View {
    public func applyStyle(_ style: Style){
        // USe the style here
    }
}


// Initializg the data
let mockedData: [Preset] = [
    .init(title: "Title A", style: StyleA()),
    .init(title: "Title A", style: StyleB()),
    .init(title: "Title A", style: StyleC()),
]

myView.applyStyle(mockedData.first!.style)
```